# Deadlock from mysqldump --single-transaction, is it possible?

Tags: mysql, backup, innodb, mysqldump, deadlock

Is it possible to get a deadlock if you ran mysqldump with the argument --single-transaction ? or any other complication ?

If it is used to backup a live site with many other querys running at the same time.

Extra info:

The mysqldump process could take over few minutes to complete.

The tables are innodb.

**EDIT**

I am concerned about the deadlocks errors that could happen on the live applications relying on the database during the time where mysqldump is running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## PROBLEM

It is logically possible because [--single-transaction](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_single-transaction) gets  ["thrown under the bus"](http://youtu.be/NyaQhNHhgw4?t=1m51s) if any `ALTER TABLE` commands are launched intermittently during the mysqldump ([See  this post from mysqlperformanceblog.com](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2012/03/23/best-kept-mysqldump-secret/)).

What happens when a dump faces off against an ALTER TABLE ?

- If session #1 is running the mysqldump on `mydb.mytable`, an `ALTER TABLE` from session #2 may pause because it needs to perform a table lock.
- If session #1 is running `ALTER TABLE` on `mydb.mytable`, it could produce spurious results from session #2 trying to run mysqldump on that table (Possible empty table [missing data])

It is not so much a deadlock in the traditional sense, but it safe to say that the `--single-transaction` option can get its loyalty displaced and lose it point-in-time window from the first victimized table and all other tables after it.

## SOLUTION

## Setup Master/Slave Replication

- Use [binlog_format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_binlog-format) = ROW to have changes as granular as possible
- Perform mysqldumps of the Data from the Slave

  - STOP SLAVE;
  - mysqldump --single-transaction ...
  - START SLAVE:

You should never encounter deadlocks as long as the Slave is used for reads and backups only.

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Does `mysqldump: Error 1213: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction when dumping table` only happen with `ALTER TABLE` or all DDL statments? I see thousends of `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` in audit log.