# Galera backup failing with error "mysqldump: Error 1213: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction when dumping table"

Tags: replication, mariadb, mysqldump, deadlock, galera

We face the same issue like this [posting on dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48962/deadlock-from-mysqldump-single-transaction-is-it-possible) *Deadlock from mysqldump --single-transaction, is it possible?*. We offer DBaaS and can't control the DDL statements of our customers.

```
mysqldump: Error 1213: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction when dumping table `x` at row: x
```

**After that error the backup fails.**

This is the backup command

```
mysqldump --max_allowed_packet=1G -u root -pvubaluaGebetee1aichaingubaePho --opt --flush-logs --single-transaction  --all-databases | bzcat -zc > /var/lib/mysql/backup/$FILE`date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S`.sql.bz2
```

The accepted solution recommends *Setup Master/Slave Replication*. We use already Galera multi master replication.

```
> select version();
+----------------------+
| version()            |
+----------------------+
| 5.5.41-MariaDB-wsrep |
+----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

other ideas howto make sure the backup completes? I don't care if a few rows not in backup.

Answer (score 2):

### Option 1

Use a replication slave off the galera cluster exclusively for creating backups. You can stop slave to ensure that all DDL operations have finished before doing a dump. Parallel dumping operations like mydumper are also possible.

Don't forget to enable log-slave-updates on the galera member you use as a master.

### Option 2

Desync a galera node before doing a backup from it.

Comment: thanks. Please provide more details howto do that? What config changes and CLI commands?

Comment: bash -c "${mysqlCommand} --execute \"SET GLOBAL wsrep_desync = ON\""

Answer (score 1):

Consider using percona-xtrabackup -it's a non blocking method. Also consider using pbzip2 (parallel bzip2) in order to speed up the backup process.